# Use yellow mustard to make mayonnaise?

Tags: mayonnaise, mustard

Is it possible to use the "american yellow mustard" (normally used as a condiment) to make mayonnaise using canola oil, eggs, and a food processor?

Or is Dijon mustard the only usable mustard for this purpose?

Comment: mustard is completely optional when making a mayonnaise

Comment: That's very interesting. May you refer a recipe for that? @Raditz_35

Comment: It would just be the same recipe that you're using already, without the mustard. It helps in terms of flavor and as an emulsifier but Raditz is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mustard is used as a flavouring - either you like whatever flavour the alternative mustard yields, or you don't - *and* as an added emulsifier. The emulsifier effect can be achieved with pretty much any mustard, be it english, french, or in powder form (mind flavor interaction with vinegar in that case...). The mayonnaise might even work without any mustard if it isn't an eggless recipe, since eggs (lecithin!) act as an emulsifier too.